# Concatenating Data Files Named with a Timestamp

Tags: linux, bash, join, sed, timestamp

Within a single directory I have a series of data files with a timestamp appended to the filename, such as `file-13-57-38-876.txt`, `file-13-57-59-288.txt`, `file-13-58-19-700.txt`, etc. where the time is listed as hour-minute-second-millisecond. Each file is formatted essentially as follows:

```
Some preamble text
that takes up a few lines
0.000 1.000
0.200 0.900
0.400 0.800
0.600 0.700
0.800 0.600
1.000 0.500
```

Each file contains points at the same x-coordinates, so I'd like to concatenate the data (probably using `join`) from all the files into a single file `alldata.txt` containing many columns, one from each file in order. Stripping all non-numerical data should be straightforward using `sed -i '/^[0-9]/ !d' *.txt`, but I'm not sure of the easiest way to troll through these files, joining them together along the way, due to the irregularities in the timestamps in the names. Is there a way to pass these files to `join` one-by-one based on their appearance 'alphabetically' within the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input files are as regular as you say - same x-coords in the same order - you could try some `bash` process substitution and script re-invocations:

```
#!/bin/bash

process() { exec sed -n '/^[0-9]/p' "$1"; }

[ $# -eq 0 ] && exit
[ $# -eq 1 ] && { process "$1"; exit; }

fn="$1"; shift
join <(process "$fn") <("$0" "$@")
```

If the above is saved as "join_em.sh", see how:

```
./join_em.sh file-*.txt
```

works for you.

Maybe take some care if you're dealing with hundreds or thousands of input files.

Comment: The input files are all very regular, so this worked great!